What is the proper way to reference assets in the new Angular 18 "public" folder structure inside a workspace?
After generating a workspace with the new @angular/cli@18 package, I am unable to determine how to reference image assets placed in the /public folder.
This did not seem to be an issue with @angular/cli@17 workspaces but they used a different asset folder name & location. v17 created a structure similar to this when using the ng new workspace-name --no-create-application command and then ng g app application-name inside that workspace:
workspace-name
 |
 projects
  |
  application-name
   |
   src
    |
    assets
  

Then, from a template you could reference an asset like so: <img src="assets/imagename.webp">
However, in v18 the created structure is generated as follows when using commands similar to above:
workspace-name
 |
 projects
  |
  application-name
   |
   public
   src

It appears that the assets are intended to go in the public folder but I have tried various permutations of pathing to reference these assets to no avail. Also, doing an ng build [application-name] does not appear to copy the files in the public folder over to the dist so maybe this has something to do with it.
It should be noted that when an app is generated without a workspace, I am able to reference assets simply by using asset-name.webp without issue. Additionally, the v18 workspace angular.json file has the following configuration automatically set for the assets property of the application build options:
"assets": [
 {
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "public"
 }
]

Is this a bug with the new builder or is there a new way to reference these assets or some additional configuration that needs to be done now that they are located in a different folder?

In angular 18 public folder config in angular.json
    "assets": [
        {
           "glob": "**/*",
           "input": "public"
        }
    ]

for example to load logo.png in "public/img/logo.png"
just remove public/ in url.
<img src="img/icon.png" />


This is exactly what I was looking for in regards to an ng18 project, but the example has malformed JSON with opening quotes on the keys missing. Should be:
 {
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "public"
 }


Me too, I initially had only the /public folder (no /assets folder created by "ng new project-name", Angular CLI 18.0.2), and couldn't load images from /public.
I had to create the "assets" folder myself under "public": /public/assets (and I placed my image here).
Then, <img src="/assets/test.png"> worked.

Solution
After doing a little investigating it looks like the @angular/cli did not set the projects.applicationName.architect.build.assets property in the angular.json file properly. Changing over the input property from public to projects/applicationName/public did the trick. Now I am able to reference assets simply with asset-name.webp.
I have opened an issue on the @angular/cli repo with regard to this so hopefully someone there can address this problem.

I had the same issue today when starting a new Angular 18 project. It seems Angular looks for images in the /public/assets folder.
I used a relative path in the img tag like this: src="/assets/image.png", and it worked for me. Other path options didn't work.

solution to image in angular 18:
in angular 18 version there is not "assets" folder.
if you want to put in your project images, you put the images in the "public" folder and not in the assets folder and you will write in the src of the img the name of the image without any routing.
for example:
if this is the name of the image:

"2.JPG"

so you write in the img tag:

< img src="2.JPG" alt="">

and you dont have to write all the route.
i hope i helped and it will be usefull.

This is the angular.json assets array. It does not have to be modified.
"assets": [
    {
       "glob": "**/*",
       "input": "public"
    }
]

Just put your images folder in the public folder of your application. In my case my images are in public/assets/img. angular.json does not have to be modified.
I reference my images like so:
<img src="assets/img/{{img}}">


In case that helps anyone (because it took me some time):
If you're trying to reference a locally hosted font in a .css, you need to reference it with an absolute path and don't forget the ^ at the beginning of the path.
In this case, my .css is in src/ and the config for the font in public/fonts looks like this:
@font-face {
    font-family: Inter;
    src: url('^./../../public/fonts/Inter-VariableFont_opszwght.ttf') format('truetype');
}


I was building a new mfe federation host and remote, remote worked perfectly fine, but the host app had issues loading federation.manifest.json, looks like angular 18 by default angular does not move public assets on dev, in this case we should set the output option under assets array in angular.json file.
"assets": [{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "projects/host/public",
  "output": "public"
}],


I use Angular 18.2.8 version.
I tried multiple things and in the end it worked.
It's important to know that the public folder is created by angular and it's in the same folder as src folder.
The folder stucture is this:
src
public
    |images
        |Product_01.jpg

In the end it worked with this path:
<img src="images/Product_01.jpg">

I did not modified angular.json. This contains:
"assets": [
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "public"
    }
]


How to Properly Reference Assets in Angular 18
In Angular 18 the structure for referencing assets has changed and assets are now managed inside the public folder, earlier assets were placed under the src/app/assets directory.
In latest version angular, the angular.json configuration automatically includes the necessary setup for the public folder, so you don't need to manually configure it. By default, Angular will look for assets in the public directory during the build process.
Step 1:
Place all your assets like images, videos, fonts, etc., inside the public folder like given below
public/
└── assets/
    └── images/
        └── ai-loading.gif

Step 2: In your component.html you can reference these assets directly using the path starting from assets.
<img src="assets/images/ai-loading.gif" id="loader-image" width="300px" />

Since Angular serves the public folder at the root level, so you don't have to specify /public/ in the path just start from assets/.

I had the similar issue few days back at Angular 18.2. After creating 'assets' folder under 'public' folder it works for me.
If still not working for you just run the 'ng serve' or 'ng dev' command again.
<img src="/public/assets/logo.png" alt="logo" />


You just need to put assets folder in correct order,as mentioned in the following
to add in src of img tag
use this
'assets/...'
enter image description here
