"ng new ..." command doesn't create an assets folder automatically and when I add one manually the assets are not found
When I create a new Angular project with the ng new ... command, there is no assets folder automatically created. Furthermore, when I add an assets folder myself and add its path to the angular.json file, following the instructions from the Angular documentation, the assets are not found, and I get the following error message in the web console:
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4200/assets/images/image1.jpg
(I'm on Mac)
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets/",
    "output": "/assets/"
  },
  {
    "glob": "favicon.ico",
    "input": "src/",
    "output": "/"
  }
]

This is how I added the assets folder I created to the angular.json file. I also tried the other way described in the documentation; both are not working for me:
"assets": [
  "src/assets",
  "src/favicon.ico"
]

And this is how I embedded the image into the html:
<img src="assets/images/image1.jpg" class="logo" alt="logo image"/>
Thanks for your help!

This might occur if your paths are not correct. Try ./ instead of /

When I create a new angular project, there is assets folder. I don't know why you don't have it. The img tag in HTML looks correct. Make sure the assets array is in the correct location in angular.json. And
Assets folder must be under src.
{
  "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

According to the angular version, this sequence may differ. (My version is 17.0.0)
When you run 'ng build', you should see assets as a separate folder.

I guess your version is 18.0 Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78526073/what-is-the-proper-way-to-reference-assets-in-the-new-angular-18-public-folder .
